# Swift Extensions

Tags: ios, swift

I am curious as to what is the purpose of writing extensions for a class that you can already add code?

For example, in [Ray Wenderlich's AlamoFire](https://www.raywenderlich.com/121540/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial,

He has a ViewController class, but he writes an extension for that ViewController for his Networking Functions and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods. Is the only reason he is writing extensions is for the purpose of dividing up code into logical bits?

Is this a common practice or just personal preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something Apple does too. If you look at the code (let's say the `Array` struct) you can see that every conformance to a protocol is *encapsulated* inside an extension.

The only difference is that your code is better separated. But it really is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it common practice, but I know that I do it because it creates compartmentalized of code. If you need something you just go to the designated extension. However, I believe it is just personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

One use not mentioned: adding to source code you don't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

It's `Protocol-Oriented Programming`, here is some useful links: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/
https://www.raywenderlich.com/109156/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-2

Answer (score 0):

This is a convention, one which Apple personally follows.

Personally I like it a lot, as it allows you to break up large monolithic classes into smaller, more manageable parts.

In particular, making extensions to separate protocol conformances makes your code a lot more readable. It serves a similar purpose as the `#pragma mark` preprocessor macro in Objective-C.